# Is Drupal good for managing users and processing users' comments

Tags: drupal, web, content-management-system

I'm looking to build a website which displays a selection of items. The end users can post comments, tags, ratings, etc. about an item and I want to use an algorithm to process those comments (etc.) and distill information. For example, if a lot of people use the same word about this item, I would like to display that information differently. Besides, I want high level of interactivity with the visual elements on the site and a way to manage users' database (log in, summary page, inbox etc.) but without any e-commerce or complex social media functions.

I have background in HTML, Java, and FLEX so you can see I'm not a veteran web developer. That's why I want to use a CMS. I'm looking in to Drupal now since it's an efficient and multi-purposed CMS but honestly I have very little knowledge about any other platforms. So I wonder if it's good or suitable for my purpose.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: See [help/on-topic], point #4: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Comment: Check http://pligg.com/ .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In short: yes, Drupal could handle this in a best way. I would suggest you to build a free Drupal 7 site using https://www.drupalgardens.com/ to test features you need.

[Please also read about main Drupal's features.](https://www.drupalgardens.com/features)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any personal favorite source for learning Dupral?

Comment: 1. Drupal's code is a very good commented so you could just read code.

2. Drupal API is great! https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/7

3. Drupal's documentation is good point to start. https://www.drupal.org/documentation